# Brightness control does not work in Ubuntu 13.04 on Sony Vaio

Tags: brightness, system-settings

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 in my Sony Vaio laptop.

When I try to reduce the brightness it is not working.

The brightness remains 100% all the time even when I try to reduce it through System Settings.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps and your brightness key will start working:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your system.

Answer (score 0):

If your notebook has an nvidia graphics card, then you're gonna have a bad time. First of all, if you are using the nvidia proprietary driver, there are two issues I have noticed:

1. The start animation (the one showing the Ubuntu logo with the dots), doesn't fully work. I've read that the nvidia proprietary driver doesn't fully support the screen resolution on the start window (don't ask me why).
2. Some custom controls of your notebook (especially brightness control) don't work at all with nvidia's proprietary driver.

However, on the login screen, animations work better with the proprietary driver than with the nouveau driver, or in general, all animations and graphic stuff work better with the proprietary driver, apart from those mentioned earlier.

So the optimal solution is for instance to use the nouveau open source driver if you don't need high graphics performance, or else, just deal with the fact that you won't be able to change the screen brightness, at least not easily.